# Retrieving categories for a specific subject from DBpedia

Tags: categories, dbpedia

How to transform the following query

> SELECT DISTINCT ?category WHERE {?subject dcterms:subject ?category} LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0

to retrieve the categories for a specific subject, e.g. Eiffel_Tower?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?category
WHERE {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Eiffel_Tower> dcterms:subject ?category
}
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```